# How to use an existing Mapbox GL "template" but add elevation/fog to it?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have this:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map
({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11',
});
```

It works. But I also want elevation/fog added to it. Reading the manual for many hours, it seems to me that you **either** have to specify a URL, like I have done, to a "pre-made style", **OR** specify an absolutely **massive** style object full of cryptic and incomprehensible sub-objects such as specific layers and stuff.

There doesn't seem to be a way to simply use that style "template" URL, *and* add elevation/fog on top of it. I really hope that I'm wrong about this.

Downloading the JSON object representing their "pre-made style", I was presented with a **massive** ocean of data, impossible to manage in any sensible manner. They cannot possibly mean that you should try to edit/adapt/extend that.

I must be missing something. Is there really no way to do what I do now, but enable the "terrain" and "fog" features?

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/terrain/
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/fog/

Naturally, I tried adding them to the `Map` object at first, assuming this was how it was done, but it was just ignored.

Again, if I were to make my own `style` object, it would be required to contain all sorts of scary and incomprehensible stuff: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/root/

To be frank, I have no idea who would ever want a 3D map which *can* support elevation/height differences and realistic fog/lights, yet *not* use those features. To me, this seems like it would be a simple boolean setting that you turn on/off, and which is enabled by default.

Comment: It's not "cryptic and incomprehensible". The style specification is very well documented. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this, but you should be able to set fog dynamically like this:

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map
({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11',
});

map.on('load', () => {
  map.setStyle({
    ...map.getStyle(), 
    "fog": {
        "range": [-0.5, 3],
        "color": "white",
        "horizon-blend": 0.1
    }
  })
});
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/fog/).

Comment: Thank you. This turned out to work, a bit surprisingly. Which is great. But it really, genuinely frustrates me beyond words that I had to ask the community about this instead of them simply... you know... having a minimal example or any kind of information on how to accomplish this. The documentation is practically useless in practice if you think about it. Making your own "style" from scratch would be a monumental undertaking, taking me many months of hard work.

Comment: I don't agree with your comments on the documentation, but glad I could help.